# Hibernate Single Table Inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two Entities BillingAddress and ShippingAddress mapped to TABLE ADDRESS having discriminator TYPE column.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE",discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "1")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Shippingaddress.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Shippingaddress s")})
public class Shippingaddress  implements Serializable{}

@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "2")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Billingaddress.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM Billingaddress b")})
public class Billingaddress extends Shippingaddress implements Serializable {}
```

I am able to save/update the two address type successfully in DB with different TYPE values.

The problem I am facing is when I am querying ADDRESS table as follows:

```
Session session=getCurrentSession();
        Query query=session.createQuery("from Billingaddress where userId.userId=:userId");
        query.setLong("userId", userId);
        billingaddress=(Billingaddress)query.uniqueResult();
```

This works fine , but querying ShippingAddress throws NonUniqueResult Exception ie I get both Shippingaddress and Billingaddress in result. Please let me know , what should I do differently.

```
Session session=getCurrentSession();
        Query query=session.createQuery("from Shippingaddress where userId.userId=:userId");
        query.setLong("userId", userId);
        shippingaddress=(Shippingaddress)query.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Do you have two rows (one with TYPE=1 and one with TYPE=2) for the given userId? If so, that's quite expected, since a BillingAddress is also a ShippingAddress, by your definition. My guess is that you should have a base abstract class Address, and two concrete subclasses BillingAddress and ShippingAddress. A BillingAddress shouldn't be a subclass of ShippingAddress.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you are right , I created an abstract base class with all the attributes in it.And Shippingaddress and Billingaddress as subclasses only having the discriminator and entity annotation. And now , it works.:)

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another solution is to create an abstract class Address and map the column in the parent class with "insertable = false, updatable = false"

Then you can add the type in your query:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE",discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Address.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Address s where type = :type")})
public class Address implements Serializable {
    @Column(name="TYPE", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Integer type;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "1")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Shippingaddress.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Shippingaddress s")})
public class Shippingaddress  implements Serializable{}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "2")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Billingaddress.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM Billingaddress b")})
public class Billingaddress extends Shippingaddress implements Serializable {}
```

then you can write "from Address where type = 1" is the same as "from Shippingaddress" and "from Address" will retrieve all rows

Answer (score 1):

DiscriminatorColumn & DiscriminatorValue don't works on the same class... i suggest you to define an abstract class like this...

Try this configuration for Hierarchy structure

**ShippingaddressAbstract.java**

```
@Table(name = "address")
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE",discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class ShippingaddressAbstract implements java.io.Serializable {

}
```

**Shippingaddress.java**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "1")
public class Shippingaddress extends ShippingaddressAbstract {

}
```

**Billingaddress.java**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "2")
public class Billingaddress  extends ShippingaddressAbstract {

}
```

Comment: May be you are right , but most of the examples show that DiscriminatorColumn & DiscriminatorValue can go in the same place.For example see this [link](http://java.boot.by/scbcd5-guide/apes03.html)

Comment: They can be on the same base class. But the problem is that BillingAddress is defined as a subclass of ShippingAddress. So every BillingAddress **is a** ShippingAddress. So when you query for shipping addresses, Hibernate returns all the shipping addresses matching the criteria, including billing addresses, since they **are** shipping addresses.

Comment: @Amardeep you are right but .. The problem is when you find an entity not when you persist it.