# Hibernate Single Table, query for all rows

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql-9.3

So, I'm used to used to using Hibernate 4 with Annotations for some time now.  I have traditionally done 1 concrete class per table, done and done, and this has always worked for me.

Now, I am still using Hibernate 4.3.11, and I am using Single Table Hierarchy for the first time.  I have a main/root class as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mytable")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "myobject_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "ABC")
public class MyEntity extends BaseEntity
```

So, I was wondering if this class should be abstract class???  It doesn't seem like it needs to be.

The SubClass is defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "XYZ")
public class XyzEntity extends MyEntity
```

I created a DAO for MyEntity, and the unit tests for these methods create/update/findById all seem to work ... but "getAllList" does not seem to.

```
@Override
public List<MyEntity> getAllList()
{
    List<MyEntity> myList = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from MyEntity").list();
    return myList;
}
```

When I unit test this method, I get an error message.

```
org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=708] was not of the specified subclass [com.myapp.server.model.common.MyEntity] : Discriminator: XYZ
```

I should say that I have 4 records in the database.  2 records have a value in "myobject_type" field as "XYZ" and the other have a value of "ABC"

So, I am wondering if I should even bother having a DiscriminatorValue in my root class???  I made that field "myobject_type" not null so, I would make sure every record had a discrimator value "ABC" for a record from MyEntity, and a value for "XYZ" if a XyzEntity was created.   Likewise a new MnoEntity might have a value of "MNO" in that field.

And just curious, in this whole hierarchy, If I had two SubClasses of MyEntity, can I have the same field in both these sub-entities?   Or, I suppose I could move anything like that, a field used in more than one place to the root entity.

Again, this is my first time with Single Table Hierarchy in Hibernate, and I just need to work around this error message.  Any help would be most appreciated!!!  Thanks!

Tom

Comment: Have you looked at this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349239/hibernate-single-table-inheritance

Comment: Yes.   I did an extensive search on this question, and I have looked at dozens of pages on a correct example for SIngle Table Hierarchy.  Some examples showed that the base class/entity does NOT have to be abstract, and I can certainly make the class abstract, and the problem goes away.  But in the event the app I am working on DOES need this root class, I just wanted to know if I could fix this?

Comment: In the question i posted, the user created another abstract class with insertable=false, updateable= false, so you could still use your root class

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the SQL Query filtering for this values directly in the query creation  instead of do this with  @DiscriminatorColumn and @DiscriminatorValue.

```
 List<MyEntity> myList = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from MyEntity where myobject_type != :pattern").setParameter("pattern", pattern).list();
return myList;
```